# Is there a Google hangout button on iPhone?

Tags: google-hangouts

The new Google hangout button enables to embed hangouts on websites, but it is not supported by iPhone.

Google + iPhone app enables hangouts with iPhone devices.

Is there a way to use a hangout on iPhone with the hangout button?